# Changing the width of a <select> item in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am new to HTML, and I'm trying to build a mobile app using phoneGap and jQuery plug-in. I am currently programing using eclipse, In my app I have a drop dwon menu (select) with a couple of items in it. I am trying to change the width of the select item, but it doesnt work. here you can see what have i done to solve this:

```
<label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose Expiry Date</label>
        <select id="date" name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" style="width:150px">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
        <option value="">3</option>
        <option value="">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want it to change size based on the selected option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#date').css('width', 'new_Value');
```

From jQuery Mobile Documentation:

Refreshing a select

If you manipulate a select via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling. Here is an example:

```
var myselect = $("select#foo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Comment: how did you add this function into your code? how did you trigger it?

Comment: I used your code like this:<script type="text/javascript">  YOUR CODE</script>

Comment: That doesn't work, because a) you need to call it on the load of the body that way by using function(){$('#date').css('width', 'new_Value');

} and b) it will only be called once. Makram's example is actually pretty precise and explains perfectly what you have to do

Comment: when u said foo, does it mean the same as "date" from your previews answer??

Comment: In your case you would replace $("select#foo") with $("#date") or $("select#date"), yes

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/x472U/

Comment: it didnt work either, you need to know that I am using jQuery mobile framework!

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#date").change(function() {
 $(this).css({'width':'78px'});
  });
```

From the jqueryMobile Documentation:

Refreshing a select

If you manipulate a select via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling. Here is an example:

```
var myselect = $("select#foo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

So if you do change the width, you still need to refresh it

Comment: do as Semyazas suggests write document.ready or function and include the js code inside it

Comment: After the OP finally being clear on using jQuery Mobile, the problem got reproducable

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is wrap your select menu:

```
<div id="mySelect">
   <select id="cities">
    ...
   </select>
</div>
```

Then you can manipulate your select width size from javascript or css:

CSS:

```
#mySelect{ width: 150px; }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#mySelect").css({"width":"150px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm what you have done is correct, select element width is either controlled by the size of the option inside it or the CSS width.

Example based off your code (that works):

http://jsfiddle.net/7Wuq2/

Comment: well its seems really strenge to me, because it doesnt work by me.

Comment: I can assure you that indeed the select box is 250px in the above example. If you question is somehow different, care to elaborate up top?

Comment: it didnt work, I am using jQuery mobile frame work, the thing is I used to have the same problem with the textfields but then somehow I was able to solve that problem when I used width,