# how to force width for select tag in mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a extra long select tag in my mobile page. and when I select an option, the select tag occupies several "lines" ([click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQn20.png)).

The problem happens on iOS and Android. Any ideas on how to fix to force the browser to display the option in 1 line only?

I've tried:

1. using selectmenu to set width

   ```
   $("#country").selectmenu({width: 50});
   ```
2. tried using style parameter to set width

   ```
   <select style="width: 50px !important" name="institution" id="institution">
   ```

Both options doesn **NOT** work. Any ideas on how to do what I want? I also searched the net but found nothing.

Comment: but even if it's 150px, it just wraps arounds. I do not want it to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on another stackoverflow page. this might help you.

"ttp://jsfiddle.net/x472U/"

---

Reference: "[Changing the size (width) of a select item in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842865/changing-the-size-width-of-a-select-item-in-html)"